# How to set autolayout so image takes up full screen?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have the image to cover the page but when you rotate the phone the image does not cover the full screen in landscape. What am I missing?

```
func setBackgroundImage() {
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "newbackground")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
    backgroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is you are setting a frame and then turning off the auto resizing mask, which implies you are using auto layout. What constraints have you set?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27198660/1630618

Comment: I actually had not set any. I thought that I could just do that with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could track that the device's orientation has changed.
So far your code does use the `UIScreen.main.bounds` of portrait mode.

Try using this tracking the change of orientation with a `Notification` like this:

**in ViewDidLoad add:**

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

**Add rotated function:**

```
func rotated() {
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
   // change frame of subview in here
} else {
   // change frame again in case you rotated back.
}
}
```

be careful using this in terms of having the option of Portrait Upside Down etc.

Comment: Well that makes sense. Thank you! I am actually new to IOS DEV. How do set  an image on top of the background? I got an array of images, but how to I set the images on top of the background? et diceImage = UIImage(named: "\(diceArray)")
        view.addSubview(diceImage)
        diceImage.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
        diceImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        diceImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

Comment: what do you mean by top of background?

Comment: Well in front of the background. bc when I added the image it did not show up on screen.

Comment: How would I insert an imageview on top of another. So that the background is behind the other imageview.

Comment: I am not sure, if I get your request clear. You are adding more than 1 Subview to your View and you want 1 specific view in front? Try using `childView.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: childView)`

Comment: right, I want to create a UIView that holds a background and have another UI view in front of the view.

Answer (score 1):

one more step after `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, set up and activate the autolayout constraints.

```
func setBackgroundImage() {
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "newbackground")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)

    backgroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        backgroundImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        backgroundImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
        backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])


}
```

Comment: Ohhhh. I forgot to set the constraints. Well that makes sense. Thank you! I am actually new to IOS DEV. Been struggling with the storyboard constraints and was looking through youtube for a way to do it in code.