# Xcode 9 Interface Builder: How to make an Image View fill the window?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm working on a MacOS app, and I have an Image View in Interface Builder which is the child of a Window. I would like the image to be centered in the window, and resized so it's big enough to completely fill the window.

I have tried setting a constraint on the size of the Image View from the constraints menu at the bottom. This constrained the window the size of the image - what I want is the opposite. I would like to not have any constraints on the size of the window.

I have seen in [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197799/xcode-6-how-to-make-an-image-view-fill-the-screen-on-all-devices-auto-layout-n) people have been informed to set the "mode" to "aspect fill". However there is no "mode" dropdown when I have my Image View selected.

Comment: Add constraints to tie the edges of the imageview to the edges of the parent view. Don't add height and width constraints.

Comment: @Ron This makes the window extremely wide and does not change the size of the picture. I did this from the constraints menu in the bottom (with the four text boxes arranged around a square icon representing the window).

Comment: Have you experimented with the image-view's content-compression resistance priority? Setting the relevant width and height values to low numbers (e.g. ~100) might help you achieve the effect you're after. You can then experiment with the scaling value of the image-view - if you don't care about your image being stretched, try selecting 'Axes Independently'.